# Determine URL of a users YouTube channel

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube API (v2) and can't find a reliable way of linking to a users youtube page.

If they are a normal user then I can put their username in the URL such as:
http://www.youtube.com/user/user-NAME-goes-here

But if its a channel then the username seeems to come back as a garbled mess and doesn't work. I've found that you can put "UC" in front of the user ID and change /user/ to /channel/ as follows:
http://www.youtube.com/channel/user-ID-goes-here

But how do I know if its a channel or a normal user so I make the adjustment?